# Air Intake Issues on Chevy Cruze (Lack of Power, Jerking, Etc)

Tags: chevrolet, power, cruze

**Car Details**

- 2013 Chevy Cruze
- History of Coolant issues, in the past 4 years I've replaced the water outlet valve, many many hoses, thermostat, temperature sensors, and ending with the radiator a few months ago.
- A week or so ago I started having lack of power issues which felt like the vehicle not wanting to shift gears.

**Thrown Codes**

- P0101
- P1011
- P0299
- P0300

**What I've Tried**

- Replaced Air Filter today (FRAM 10989). I noticed that I used a different type of air filter last time I replaced it (it looked like my current one but has a fuzz glued to the bottom of it [similar to this air filter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004JBI5HG)).
- Test drove it about a mile afterwards. At first it was doing more of the same (lack of power and jerking), but after a minute or two it started driving normally, so I decided to go get gas. It behaved perfectly on the way to the gas station.
- On the way home from the gas station it started acting worse than ever (even more jerking) so I eased off the accelerator and drove home slower.
- Once home, I noticed the hole in the hose (see image below). I'm unsure if it had been there and I didn't notice it or if that was new (I'd like to think I would have noticed that).
- I cleared engine codes after changing the air filter. All the same error codes are back again after that test drive. I *think* the P0300 might be new, not sure.

[image: Hose with the hole]
[image: Sensor that goes in the hole]

**Questions**

1. Obviously, I need to replace that hose and possibly the sensor attached, but I don't know its name. What is the name of the hose?
2. Once I've replaced this hose, how should I go about troubleshooting this issue without causing more damage? I've read to check the MAF sensor next, but how to do I safely check the vehicle is operating properly without the risk of further damage?

Comment: I'm assuming you're stating some type of sensor goes in the hole? Where is the original sensor and the wiring belonging to the sensor? If you have the original sensor, could you post a picture of it? This is the air intake tract? Is the engine turbocharged?

Comment: I added a photo of the sensor. I finally found the part. It's the `Turbocharger Intercooler Hose` according to this link: https://www.amazon.com/GM-Genuine-13345223-Turbocharger-Intercooler/dp/B08NM7BTC6
Couldn't find it before because the aftermarket ones you find on Autozone and such places look very different and don't have a sensor despite claiming to match my vehicle. Not sure if I'm going to need to replace the sensor too or not. I guess I'll take it one step at a time. Still worried about causing similar problems again if this wasn't the original cause.

Comment: I believe the sensor is the MAF, which if it isn't doing it's thing, will cause the car to run very poorly. That and the hole in the charge pipe is most likely causing all your issues.

Comment: After further research, the hose is the `Turbocharger Intercooler Hose` and the attached sensor is the `Turbocharger boost pressure sensor`. The MAF sensor is on the left side of the engine next to the air filter. I looked into how much crap I have to remove to replace that hose and opted to take it into a shop. I'll post a status update once they've replace the hose and whether anything else needed replaced in case it is helpful to others. Apparently, the shop had a note that they noticed my turbocharger cooler was dented when they replaced my radiator.

Comment: The sensor you are referring to can also be called a MAP (Manifold Absolute Pressure) sensor, which would feed the boost charge pressure from the turbo back to the ECU. Without that talking to the ECU, it would continually believe the only pressure going through the hose would be at atmospheric and not at whatever boost level it should be showing. This is one of the key sensors which provides the data needed by the ECU to provide fueling and spark advance. You'll most likely get all kinds of lean misfires due to this (random across all cylinders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the car back from the shop, they replaced the hose & sensor as well as my Turbocharger Intercooler because it was severely dented. Car is running great. AC is actually running better too weirdly enough.

So it would appear the air intake issues were specifically that sensor/hose being separated. I believe they became separated while driving it with the Turbocharger Intercooler being damaged.

Comment: As an update, my Turbocharger Intercooler was dented and causing the whole region to get too hot causing the issue above (and a lot of other cooling issues, mostly  the plastic parts of the cooling system melting like the outlet valve, thermostat, etc). Long journey, but it's been about a year since fixing this hose, sensor, and the intercooler itself and I haven't had any more problems.